# Error 4005 when running ExtractFile in a scheduled agent

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript

I have a scheduled LotusScript agent that I want to loop through documents in a view and extract the attached file(s) to a folder on the server:

```
'extract file
If Not IsEmpty(rtitem.embeddedObjects) Then
    ForAll o In rtitem.EmbeddedObjects
        If (o.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT) Then
            Call o.ExtractFile("\\TestServer\TestFolder\"+o.name)
        End If
    End ForAll
End If
```

This agent works fine when ran through the Notes client. However, when the agent is scheduled I get the following error: "Error: 4005 - Notes error: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password". It errors at the "Call o.ExtractFile(..." line above.

I've tried changing the security level on the agent to "Allow restricted operations with full admin rights" and "Run as Web user" but the error persists.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the server has access to the file share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a network error and not an error within Lotus Notes.  Make sure the account under which the server is running has access to the share.

Comment: I used to have a similar issue. What I did then is I saved the file to the local disk of the domino server and copied the file to the network drive using a scheduled task / chron job. I think this is necessary when your domino server does runs using the system account on windows.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. As you stated, the issue was with the access. What I ended up doing is using the drive letter on the server instead of the network path: Call o.ExtractFile("D:\TestFolder\"+o.name)

Answer (score 0):

1. This is very common issue: If you are going to extract the file on
   some location then also check the drive is exists on server or not.
2. Make sure you have proper rights to create a file on the folder, it means folder should have full access.
3. Agent should have proper rights.